# How to access specific json field in a select statement along with count function?

Tags: json, postgresql, left-join

I am trying to access the specific section of the JSON field in PostgreSQL with count function, to get the medias with the status of alt text is present or not.

**Tables with data:**

**properties**

```
id cid property_name
1  11   abc
2  11   pqr
3  11   xyz
4  11   ddd
5  11   eee
6  11   fff
```

**marketing_media_associations**

```
id cid property_id media_path   details
1   11    1          path1      {"filemeta1":"aa", "media_alt":"media alt text", "filemeta2":"meta2 text"}
2   11    2          path1      {"filemeta1":"aa", "filemeta2":"meta2 text"}
3   11    3          path1      {"filemeta1":"aa", "media_alt":"media alt text2", "filemeta2":"meta2 text"}
4   11    6          path1      {"filemeta1":"aa", "filemeta2":"meta2 text"}
5   11    6          path1      {"filemeta1":"aa", "media_alt":"media alt text2", "filemeta2":"meta2 text"}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
id property_name media_alt
1   abc          YES
2   pqr          NO
3   xyz          YES
4   ddd          -
5   eee          -
6   fff          YES
```

I am trying to execute the following query, but it is not giving me the expected result.

```
SELECT p.id, p.property_name,
            (CASE WHEN COUNT(mma.details->'media_alt' ) > 0 THEN 'YES'
            WHEN COUNT(mma.cid) > 0 THEN 'NO'
            ELSE '-'
            END) as media_alt
FROM properties p
LEFT JOIN marketing_media_associations mma ON ( mma.property_id = p.id AND mma.cid = p.cid )
GROUP BY p.id, p.property_name ORDER BY p.property_name
```

How would the right SQL look like?

Comment: Can `marketing_media_associations` table content more then one record for property?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IS NULL` condition instead count:
(this query valid only for case single marketing_media_associations fro each property)

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.property_name,
    (CASE 
        WHEN mma.cid IS NULL THEN '-' -- no matched row in mma table
        WHEN mma.details->'media_alt' IS NULL THEN 'NO' -- json key not exists in exists row
        ELSE 'YES'
    END) as media_alt
FROM properties p
LEFT JOIN marketing_media_associations mma ON ( mma.property_id = p.id AND mma.cid = p.cid )
ORDER BY p.property_name;
```